# Replace string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to replace a string followed by any number with NULL .

Example `[tag:1234:test][tag:5678:sql]`

Here i need to replace tag:1234: with null

Result should be : `[test][sql]`

** tag string will be constant ,Numbers will vary .

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('[tag:1234:test][tag:5678:sql]', '\\[tag:\\d+:([^\\]]+?)\\]', '[\\1]', 'g')
```

It's done by using `regexp_replace` function with suitable regular expression and `g` (global) flag for replacing all matches.

Comment: Thanks for Quick Reply ! Works Fine !

Comment: @user3007361 -- if pumbo's answer satisfies your original question, please mark it as correct so that future people with a similar problem will know it met your needs